# Additivity of the Field of Values

Tags: matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

If $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, then the *field (of values)*, or *numerical range  of A*, is the compact, convex subset of the complex-plane defined by
$$
F(A)= \{z^* A z \mid z^*z = 1 \}.
$$

It is well-known that the field is *sub-additive* in the sense that 
\begin{equation}
F(A+B) \subseteq F(A) + F(B), \tag{1}\label{fov}
\end{equation}
where addition-symbol on the right denotes Minkowksi addition.

**Question:** Is there a characterization known for when equality holds in \eqref{fov}?

Notice that if $A = UDU^*$ and $B= U \hat{D} U^*$, with $U$ unitary and $D$, $\hat{D} $ diagonal, then it is easily shown that equality holds.

**EDIT:** <del>But this condition is not necessary as equality also holds when</del> $B = cA$, $c \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a partial answer, but maybe an important case.

If $A$ is hermitian, $F(A)$ is the interval $[\lambda_{\text{min}}(A), \lambda_{\text{max}}(A)]$, where $\lambda_{\text{min}}(A)$ and $\lambda_{\text{max}}(A)$ are the minimum and maximum eigenvalues of $A$.  Thus if $A$ and $B$ are both hermitian, $F(A+B) = F(A) + F(B)$ means $\lambda_{\text{min}}(A+B) = \lambda_{\text{min}}(A)+\lambda_{\text{min}}(B)$ and similarly for $\lambda_{\text{max}}$.  That will happen if and only if
$A$ and $B$ share a common eigenvector for their minimum eigenvalues and share a common eigenvector for their maximum eigenvalues.

EDIT: It is **not** true that equality holds when $B = cA$, $c \in \mathbb C$.  For example, suppose $A = \pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$ and $B = i A$.  Then
$F(A) = [0,1]$, $F(B) = i[0,1]$, and $F(A)+F(B)$ is the convex hull of $0$, $1$, $i$ and $1+i$, but $F(A+B)$ is only the convex hull of $0$ and $1+i$.